# Return option text if users clicks on a deactivated option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-select

I have a select with a deactivated option. I need to return the text of that option in a alert if a users clicks on it.

```js
jQuery('#test.option').click(function() {
    alert(jQuery(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test'>
  <option>AAAAAAAA</option>
  <option>BBBBBBBB</option>
  <option disabled="disabled">CCCCCCCC</option>
</select>
```

This is just an example, I have real plans though. I have a backend where I am creating the select with each option and there I can specify the text which should show per option, and I need the id or text of the option, to find the according text which is rendered to the DOM but hidden.

But it does seem to be impossible to add a click event to a option.

Edit: This is not a duplicate, since I am talking about select options not inputs.

Comment: Disabled elements do not listen to click events.

Comment: ^ which means what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Ok thx, I guess I have to use jQuery UI then and fake the select and options with spans, then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of in that case, is to remove the `disabled` and create the effect using CSS. And then prevent using JS the user from selecting it. I didn't go far to manipulate the CSS as I'm trying to resolve the JS problem, but you can go ahead and work your way around the CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var previous;

  $("#test").on('focus', function() {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value;
  }).change(function() {
    // If it's the option we want to disable, we set the select as the previous value
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
      alert("Nope!")
      $('#test').val(previous);
    } else {
      // Make sure the previous value is updated
      previous = this.value;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.isDisabled {
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option class="isDisabled">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this workaround

```js
var lastSel;
  
$("#test").on('focus', function () {
  if ($('option:selected', this).attr('data-disabled') != "true") {
   lastSel = $("#test").prop('selectedIndex');
  }
}).change(function() {
  if ($('option:selected', this).attr('data-disabled') == "true") {
      alert('Item is disabled')
      $("#test").prop('selectedIndex', lastSel);
    } else {
     lastSel = $("#test").prop('selectedIndex');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select id="test">
  <option>AAAAAAAA</option>
  <option>BBBBBBBB</option>
  <option data-disabled="true" style="color: grey">CCCCCC</option>
  </select>
```